# Java instanceof and byte[]

Tags: java, casting, arrays, instanceof

What I would expect is that '`potentialByteArray instanceof byte[]` would return true when `potentialByteArray` is an instance of a `byte[]`, but this doesn't seem to happen -- it's always false for some reason!

I've got a conditional that looks like the following:

```
if (!(potentialByteArray instanceof byte[])) { /* ... process ... */ }
else  {
        log.warn("--- can only encode 'byte[]' message data (got {})", msg.getClass().getSimpleName());
        /* ... handle error gracefully ... */
    }
```

...and what this outputs is the following:

```
--- can only encode 'byte[]' message data (got byte[])
```

Which means that the object actually *was* a `byte[]` but wasn't an `instanceof byte[]` somehow. So... would this work for `Byte[]` instead or something? What's really going on here, and why isn't this working as I am expecting?

What's an appropriate idiom to use here instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you have a `!` (not) that you don't need

```
if (!(potentialByteArray instanceof byte[])) {...}
```

should be

```
if (potentialByteArray instanceof byte[]) {...}
```